# What's wrong with this tic tac toe python game

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I have recently enrolled into cs50 Artificial Intelligence with python online course and the first project is to create a tic tac toe game using the minimax algorithm and I have attempted it. But when I run the runner.py file provided with the zip file from their website, it gives me some errors like for this statement:
            i = action[0] ,
saying "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
can you please correct the code or at least tell me what the problem exactly is
Thanks

```
import math
import numpy as npy
import sys
import copy

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    if board == initial_state():
        return X

    numpy_board = npy.array(board)

    Xno = npy.count_nonzero(numpy_board = X)

    Ono = npy.count_nonzero(numpy_board = O)

    if Xno > Ono:

        return O

    elif Ono > Xno:

        return X

def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    Result = set()

    for k in range(3):

        for l in range(3):

            if board[k][l] == EMPTY:

                Result.add(board[k][l])

    return Result


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    i = action[0]
    j = action[1]

    if board[i][j] != EMPTY:
        raise Exception("Invalid Action")

    new_player = player(board)

    new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)

    new_board[i][j] = new_player

    return new_board

def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    for i in range(3):

        if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] and board[i][0] != EMPTY):

            return board[i][0]

        if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] or (board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]) and board[1][1] != EMPTY):

             return board[1][1]
        if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] and board[0][i] != EMPTY):

             return board[1][i]
        else:

             return None
def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) != None:

        return True;

    numpy_board = npy.array(board)

    empty_no = npy.count_nonzero(numpy_board == EMPTY)

    if (empty_no == 0):

        return True
    else:

        return False


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    win_player = winner(board)

    if (win_player == X):

        return 1

    elif (win_player == O):

        return -1

    else:

        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None

    currentPlayer = player(board)
    if currentPlayer == X:
        return max_value(board)[1]
    else:
        return min_value(board)[1]


def max_value(board):

    if terminal(board):

        return (utility(board), None)

    value = -sys.maxsize-1

    optimalAction = None
    for action in actions(board):

        possibleResult = min_value(result(board, action))

        if possibleResult[0] > value:

            value = possibleResult[0]

            optimalAction = action


        if value == 1:
            break

    return (value, optimalAction)


def min_value(board):

    if terminal(board):

        return (utility(board), None)

    value = sys.maxsize

    optimalAction = None

    for action in actions(board):

        possibleResult = max_value(result(board, action))

        if possibleResult[0] < value:

            value = possibleResult[0]

            optimalAction = action


        if value == -1:
            break

    return (value, optimalAction)
```

Comment: The exact problem is that `action`'s value is `None`, making it a `NoneType` object, and such an object `is not subscriptable`, i.e. you cannot do the subscripting (`[0]` `[1]`) operation with it. This causes an error due to the value having the wrong type, i.e. a `TypeError`. You need to reason through your code and figure out where the value for `action` comes from.

Comment: Ok thanks I will see where it is coming from. Anything else which looks suspicious?

Comment: and there's another error due to the numpy_board variable saying, "    Xno = npy.count_nonzero(numpy_board = X)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in count_nonzero
TypeError: _count_nonzero_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numpy_board' 
Got any Idea on what that could possibly mean?

Comment: It means that when you write `count_nonzero(numpy_board = X)`, you are asking to pass X as the parameter named `numpy_board`, but the function called `count_nonzero` does not have such a parameter. Read the documentation again and double-check what you want the code to actually say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- A syntax error in `Xno = npy.count_nonzero(numpy_board = X)`. You missed an equal sign there. It should be `==`. Same error in the next similar statement
- The condition in `elif Ono > Xno:` will never be true (think about it). What's more, this condition leaves a possibility to fall through this `if..elif` without entering either block, giving a `None` return value. Either it is X's turn or it is not. In latter case it is always O's turn. You should not need a second test. So correct this line to just `else:`
- `Result.add(board[k][l])` does not add a coordinate pair, but the contents of the square. This is not what you want. You want to store the coordinates. So this should be `Result.add((k, l))`. NB: don't use Pascal case for such a name, but camel case.
- In the function `winner` the `for` loop will *aways* exit on its first iteration. It never performs the other iterations. You cannot know enough in the first iteration to return `None`. So remove that `else: return None`: in that case the loop must just continue. NB: the test for diagonals should better be moved outside of the loop, as it makes no sense to repeat that test 3 times. It does not depend on the loop variable.

If you make those corrections it should work.

Some other remarks:

- If you are going to create a numpy array out of the list, then why not create only the numpy array once from the start, and work with only that and not the list? Making the conversion each time in `player` and `terminal` has a performance impact.
- Also, counting the number of X and then the number of O needs two iterations, while you could count the empty cells in one sweep, and deduct from that how many are not empty. Even faster would be to just maintain a counter, and increase it when playing a move, and decreasing it when backtracking.
- The above mentioned counter can be used to quicly determine the current player. If the number of played moves is even, then it's X's turn, otherwise it's O's turn.
- `deepcopy` has a performance cost. Consider using the same list/array without duplicating it. You just need to add an "undo" operation after the recursive call.
- Instead of recreating the set of possible moves, also consider maintaining one set incrementatlly: remove an action from that set when you play the move, and put it back while backtracking. This will increase performance.
- Don't use this pattern:

  ```
  if (empty_no == 0):
     return True
  else:
     return False
  ```

  First of all, the parentheses are not necessary, but more importantly: when you already *have* a boolean expression (`empty_no == 0`), then just *return* it. Don't do this `if..else` stuff:

  ```
  return empty_no == 0
  ```
- The minimax algorithm only returns values -1, 0 or 1, meaning that it doesn't favour quick wins over slow wins. This may lead to surprising moves, where a direct win is not played. To improve on that, consider using a more dynamic value. One idea is to change the `utility` function so that for a win with X it returns the number of free cells, plus 1. For O it would be the negation of that value. That way quick wins are favoured.

Comment: Thanks mate... It worked as you said and thanks for all the suggestions and I will make sure to take them into practice